# Rails/ ruby error in initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this class

```
class MultipleJob < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :file
    def initialize(attributes = {})
      attributes.each { |title, value| send("#{title}=", value) }      
    end
end
```

when  i m trying to do MultipleJob.new

it is showing me

```
>> MultipleJob.new
=> #<MultipleJob not initialized>
```

Any guess why i m seeing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re subclassing ActiveRecord, which defines its own `initialize`. You should really use an [`after_initialize`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) callback instead.

But really, ActiveRecord (via [ActiveModel::Model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#model)) already does what you’re doing in your `initialize` on its own anyway, so you don’t need it at all!

Comment: I got it, but i want to set "file" so that it can be used by other methods, how can i do that ?

Comment: i m putting my complete class above to tell u what i m trying to do .

Comment: @Adt As I said, ActiveRecord/ActiveModel already gives you that ability. Did you attempt `MultipleJob.new(file: 'foo')` without your `initialize` in place?